# How to show that bounded solutions of differential equations $dx/dt=f(x)$ tend toward equilibrium (constant value) as $t\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am given $f(x)$ is a differentiable function and want to prove that the solution $x(t)$ for $dx/dt=f(x)$ tend towards equilibrium (constant value) as $t\rightarrow\infty, t\in\mathbb{R}.$

Some facts I am considering are that existence and uniqueness theorem implies that a unique solution exists for each initial condition.

$f(x)=0\implies$ x is an equilibrium and $f(x(t))$ does not change sign on a solution $x(t)$. If $x(t)$ is not an equilibrium then it is either increasing or decreasing.

Bounded solutions $x(t)$ tend to a limit, if $x(t)\rightarrow u$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$, then $u$ is an equilibrium.

I am having trouble putting these pieces together with necessary calculations. Looking for some guidance.

Comment: What do you mean by "$x$ is an equilibrium"? I've never encountered the word "equilibrium" used to describe a class of functions.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you for asking, it's when $dx/dt=0$, so if $x(t)=c$, constant solution.

Comment: So what you are actually trying to prove is that $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} x$ converges?

Comment: @PaulSinclair I believe so

Answer (score 0):

So all I can come up with so far is the following.

We assume $x(t)$ is not an equilibrium solution and that it is bounded. So $x(t)$ is either increasing or decreasing. The monotone convergence theorem states that such a function converges to its supremum if increasing and converges to infimum if decreasing.

So in short, if f is continuously differentiable and $lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$ is finite and $lim_{x\to \infty}f'(x)$ exists, then $lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x)=0$

I believe this is the basic argument but would appreciate any suggestions for more rigor.